# Trace AttachedProperty changes from code

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a custom **Control** with dependency property attached by its parent and i need to implement some hook that will be triggered on all attached property changes. In WPF it was rather easy but i have no idea how this can be achieved in WinRT environment.

For example, i have **Control** with attached property **X** and its parent is **GraphArea**. So attached property for **Control** is **GraphArea.X**.

Please give me some clues, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to do this though not exactly as i wanted to. Instead of hooking to **X** change inside every **Control** i've hooked to attached property **changed** callback of the parent.

Additionaly, i've implemented new interface for all children that must receive notification when this property changes. And as i've implemented interface methods as explicit interface implementations they are not be visible from derived classes (which is good as this operation must be internal).

Another solution is to make code-behind binding between dependency property and attached property and define OnChanged callback for DP. But in WinRT this approach only works for internal Attached Properties (not the custom created).